# using the cx_Oracle arraysize parameter with pandas read_sql

Tags: python, pandas, cx-oracle

When selecting large amounts of data from Oracle using cx_Oracle, I was finding it incredibly slow whether using pandas `read_sql` or the cx_Oracle Cursor `fetchall()` method.

Performance is drastically improved by increasing the `arraysize` attribute of the Cursor - allowing me to get decent performance out of `fetchall()`. pandas `read_sql()` takes a `Connection` object as input and the cursor is created within the function, therefore it's not obvious to me how I can apply that same setting and still take advantage of the `read_sql()` function. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `sqlalchemy` to create an engine to connect to the database, you can pass the `arraysize` argument so it will be used when cursors are created:

```
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@host:port/dbname", arraysize=50)
pd.read_sql("query ...", engine)
```

See the docs here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/dialects/oracle.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle.cx_oracle for "Additional Connect Arguments"

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks! Strange this isn't better documented on Oracle's own website.